# css bottom toolbar hiding main content

Tags: html, css

I have a bottom toolbar which is fixed to the bottom of the browser window. The problem is, when  i scroll down to the bottom of the page, part of the content gets hidden by the toolbar.

Here is the [link](http://engineer.org.in/events/mech-events/Perfect%20Machine.php#arena-specs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the `padding-bottom` on `div.content`.  80px seems like a good starting point

Answer (score 1):

You could put some padding on the bottom that is greater than the height of the bottom toolbar.

That'll make sure everything gets displayed as you'd like.

```
body
{
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```